# limits on remote desktop connection windows 2003 server

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2003

servers (50+) are managed on vmware virtualization spheres. I understand there are limits of 2 sessions for each server as mandated by windows 2003. How does network admins manage these servers? Do they have to connect to each server to perform windows administration?

Answer (score 1):

Admins for the most part do not need Remote Desktop to manage services.  Almost all databases, like MS  SQL Server, have remote administration tools.  For MS SQL Server, hey can connect to their database using MS SQL Server Management Studio.  This actually applies to pretty much any enterprise service.  Every MS service can be managed remotely without RD... even the RD service.

As for the limit of 2 users for Remote Desktop, it is an artificial limit set by Microsoft.  You can buy additional licenses to allow more remote desktop connections, but there is almost never a need.